# Rails 5 where or active record query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to write a query that counts the number of products from a supplier group that are on a specific state or return 0 if it doesn't have products.

This query will only return the count if the product exists.

```rb
SUPPLIER_GROUP_ATTRS = [
  "id",
  "count(products) as completed_products_count"
]
SupplierGroup.left_joins(:products).where("products.state=?","completed").select(SUPPLIER_GROUP_ATTRS).group(:id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `sum()` instead of `count()`, then `select case` so we can ignore your `where` clause.

```
SUPPLIER_GROUP_ATTRS = [
  "id",
  "sum(case when products.state='completed' then 1 else 0 end) as completed_products_count"
]
SupplierGroup.left_joins(:products).select(SUPPLIER_GROUP_ATTRS).group(:id)
```